# Auto Publish On Cron

Tags: cron, publish

I have some 100 unpublished posts. I want to publish 1 random post every time a cron is run.

Is there a way or plugin to achieve this...

Comment: what are the post times of all the posts?

Comment: Also, come up with a schedule of how you often you want this action to happen. cron is run on every page load, if you have something scheduled. At that rate all your posts would be published very quickly. Do you want a new post published daily/weekly/twicedaily? All those are standard schedules in WP that would be easy to set up.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out [Scheduled Draft Publish Plugin for WordPress](http://www.dagondesign.com/articles/scheduled-draft-publish-plugin-for-wordpress/):

> This plugin uses the built-in scheduling feature of WordPress to periodically take a draft post and publish it. You can define the time between occurrences, and choose to have it publish the oldest draft each time, or a random draft. By default, it publishes drafts in any category, but you can define one, or multiple, categories for it to take the drafts from.

Answer (score 1):

You can also publish posts in the future.  That way you wouldn't even need cron.